# How to zip 90days old files and move it to a specific folder using bash in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have lots of files in my FILES folder. I want to zip the files that are 90days old then remove it from the FILES folder and move it to the ARCHIVES folder using bash in linux.

This is my folder structure:

root@user:/var/FILES

root@user:/var/ARCHIVES

I have created a script to zip a file but don't know how to specify the age of the file

```
zip -r zipped.zip *.*
```

so i coded something like

```
FILE=find *.* -mtime +90
zip -r zipped.zip $FILE
```

but only returns error. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
find . -mtime +90 -exec zip zipped.zip '{}' +
```

**EDIT** If you want move zipped file to an archive folder then you can do:

```
find . -mtime +90 -exec zip zipped.zip '{}' + && mv zipped.zip /var/ARCHIVES
```

Comment: OP talls about archiving files, so should add `-type f`

Comment: how to zip each file separately?

Comment: Use `-execdir` option of `find`

Answer (score 0):

you can try `find`

```
find /var/FILES/ -type f -mtime +90 -exec zip -r zipped.zip {} \; -exec mv {} /var/ARCHIVES \;
```

Not sure whether I understand you correct, if you want to save zipped.zip in /var/ARCHIVES
just use this:

```
find /var/FILES/ -type f -mtime +90 -exec zip -r /var/ARCHIVES/zipped.zip {} \;
```

Comment: almost got it. but it only transfers the files to the ARCHIVES folder without zipping